# HTML - embedded mp4 video

Tags: html, mp4, movie, movies

I have a number of .mp4 files which have the dimensions of 1280x720. I want them to be half that size, yet when I define the width and height of the object tag etc., the video is not resized, merely zoomed in.

Is there any way of resizing it with HTML, rather than having to manually resize all the videos?

Thanks,

Will.

Comment: So rather than re-size the videos at your end and save large quantities of both bandwidth and client-side processing power, you want to resize the video in the client. I can't help but think this probably isn't the wisest of decisions.

Comment: You sir, have raised a good point. Thank you.

Comment: Let us never speak of this again. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to do that, assuming all things are equal, it will take the user 4 times longer to download the video as you expect.

Be nice to users and resize them!